# Echo an item from an array in php

Tags: php, html, arrays, simple-html-dom

I am new to php and was having a typical problem to pull some fields from an array generated by the following php code:

```
$html=file_get_html("http://www.flipkart.com/books/9781846467622");

$e = $html->getElementById("mprodimg-id");
echo $e;
$f = $e->find('img');
echo $f['data-src'];
```

The output array f as seen after applying var_dump($f) in the code is as follows:-

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object
>           (
>               [nodetype] => 1
>               [tag] => img
>               [attr] => Array
>                   (
>                       [onerror] => img_onerror(this);
>                       [data-error-url] => http://img1a.flixcart.com/img/book.jpg
>                       [height] => 275
>                       [width] => 275
>                       [data-src] => http://img7a.flixcart.com/img/622/9781846467622.jpg
>                       [src] => data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAJEAAAAAAP////Ly8v///yH5BAEAAAMALAAAAAABAAEAAAICVAEAOw==
>                       [onload] => lzld(this)
>                       [alt] => Buy Numbers
>                       [title] => Numbers
>                   )
>               [children] => Array
>                   (
>                   )
>               [nodes] => Array
>                   (
>                   )

I need to echo the value of the field "data-src". Can someone please help.

The html as seen by firebug is as follows from where i need to scrape this.

```
<div id="mprodimg-id" class="mprodimg">             
<img width="275" height="275" title="Numbers" alt="Buy Numbers" onload="lzld(this)" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAJEAAAAAAP////Ly8v///yH5BAEAAAMALAAAAAABAAEAAAICVAEAOw==" data-src="http://img7a.flixcart.com/img/622/9781846467622.jpg" data-error-url="http://img1a.flixcart.com/img/book.jpg" onerror="img_onerror(this);">
</div>
```

Comment: what does file_get_html function do?

Comment: It stores the url as html in $html variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a clean working example :

```
// includes Simple HTML DOM Parser
include "simple_html_dom.php";

$url = "http://www.flipkart.com/numbers/p/9781846467622?pid=9781846467622";

//Create a DOM object
$dom = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from url
$dom->load_file($url);


// Find the wanted image using the appropriate selectors
$img = $dom->find('#mprodimg-id img', 0);


// Find succeeded
if ($img){
    echo $img->{'data-src'};
}
else
    echo "Find function failed !";


// Clear DOM object (needed essentially when using many)
$dom->clear(); 
unset($dom);

OUTPUT
======
http://img7a.flixcart.com/img/622/9781846467622.jpg
```

[Live DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0gz-0c2)

Comment: Somehow the same thing doesn't work for $url = "http://www.flipkart.com/numbers/p/9788131200827?pid=9788131200827"; Can't understand why?

Comment: It seems that it fails following the redirection... You can try using curl to download the page then parse the dom... [Here's how](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/n0z-54d) and make sur to set `safe_mode = Off` in your `php.ini`

Comment: Hi, Enissay
I tried with your code "http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/n0z-54d" but I cant get any data. Its coming blank. Can u help me  Try http://www.flipkart.com/rena-polypropylene-knife/p/itme4anh7sym84ag?pid=KHKE4ANHNQ7KGY6U&otracker=hp_mod_homeliving_new-arrivals_prd_img